# How can I make a category in Hydejack and link it properly to the sidebar?

Tags: jekyll, categories, blogs

I am trying to make a blog by Jekyll and I chose the Hydejack theme.

I've made some posts and I wanted to sort these posts into a category named 'Algorithm'.

Of all the posts that I've made, I wrote 'categories: Algorithm' in the front matter.

```
---
layout: post
title: "This is an example post"
categories: Algorithm
data: 2023-03-24 12:25:00 +09:00
---
```

Then I made 'Algorithm.md' file in the '_featured_categories' directory according to the Hydejack documentation.

However, even though the 'categories: Algorithm' is activated, I cannot make it visible in the sidebar of my blog.

Then I inserted 'Algorithm' in my _config.yml file.

```
menu:
  - title:             Example
    url:               /example/
  - title:             Documentation
    url:               /docs/
  - title:             About
    url:               /about/
  - title:             Algorithm
    url:               /Algorithm/
```

I could see the 'Algorithm' field in my sidebar, but the problem is, if I click the 'Algorithm' in my sidebar, it says:

> 404: Page Not Found
> Sorry, we've misplaced that URL or it's pointing to something that doesn't exist. Head back home to try finding it again.

It seems like my URL of Algorithm from the menu of _config.yml is not linked properly with the Algorithm category.

I am pretty sure that I've followed the [instructions in the Hydejack documentation](https://hydejack.com/docs/basics/#adding-a-category-or-tag).

But I cannot solve this problem of linking the URL of my 'Algorithm' menu in the sidebar with the actual algorithm category I made.

Could you give me some solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this situation. All I had to do was to write the exact slug of my 'Algorithm' category to my menu in _config.yml.

I have to make sure that all the upper cases and lower cases are the same in order to link it properly.

Comment: Good to hear that you solved it. I thought about this but have not replied in time. I would only use lowercase for URLs.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question in a proper markdown syntax. I'll keep in mind to only use lowercase for URLs.